# How do I place GUI panels?

Tags: user-interface, racket, panel

I'm doing a game project in Racket and I'm stuck on the graphical part. I want to create a frame like this:

[image]

There `game-canvas` is where I wanna load my game (game not mentioned in my code), the grey area is supposed to contain nothing (only grey colour) and the buttons are supposed to be used for the game (no callback procedures for the buttons at the moment.)

My code:

```
#lang racket/gui

(define *our-frame*
  (new frame%
       [width 600]
       [height 800]
       [x 1000]
       [y 100]
       [label "Label"]
       [style '(no-resize-border)]
       ))

(define *game-panel*
  (new vertical-panel%
       [parent *our-frame*]
       [style '(border)]
       [alignment '(left center)]
       ))

(define *button-panel*
  (new vertical-panel%
       [parent *our-frame*]
       [style '(border)]
       [alignment '(right bottom)]
       ))

(define *game-button*
  (new button%
       [parent *button-panel*]
       [label "Pause"]
       [min-width 200]
       [min-height 100]
       ))

(define *new-game-button*
  (new button%
       [parent *button-panel*]
       [label "New Game"]
       [min-width 200]
       [min-height 100]
       ))

(send *our-frame* show #T)
```

This code will generate a frame with (at least what it looks like) two horizontal panels with the two buttons in the bottom right corner. How can I fix this so it appears as my picture? I've tried to change the alignment on the panels but nothing good came from that... Proberly something easy to fix but it's the first time I do graphical coding so I blame that...

Appreciates all answers!

EDIT:
In the code my button1 and button2 equals to Pause and New Game

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A frame will stack panels on top of each other.
Therefore we need to make a row of two columns: a left column and a right column.
In the left column we put the game canvas and in the right we put your panel that has the buttons.

After adding the row, and the left/right columns one needs to adjust
the `parent` clauses so everything ends up in the right places.

```
#lang racket/gui

(define *our-frame*
  (new frame%
       [width 600]
       [height 800]
       [x 1000]
       [y 100]
       [label "Label"]
       [style '(no-resize-border)]
       ))

(define *row*
  (new horizontal-panel%
       [parent *our-frame*]
       [style '(border)]))

(define *left-column*
  (new horizontal-panel%
       [parent *row*]
       [style '(border)]))

(define *right-column*
  (new horizontal-panel%
       [parent *row*]
       [style '(border)]))

(define *game-panel*
  (new vertical-panel%
       [parent *left-column*]
       [style '(border)]
       [alignment '(left center)]
       ))

(define *button-panel*
  (new vertical-panel%
       [parent *right-column*]
       [style '(border)]
       [alignment '(right bottom)]
       ))

(define *game-button*
  (new button%
       [parent *button-panel*]
       [label "Pause"]
       [min-width 200]
       [min-height 100]
       ))

(define *new-game-button*
  (new button%
       [parent *button-panel*]
       [label "New Game"]
       [min-width 200]
       [min-height 100]
       ))

(send *our-frame* show #T)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Beside your code I also added [min-width 400] in *left-column* to get it more like the picture I painted :)